# Bootstarp navbar is expanding when logged out. How to change the class of a menu button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a program where I have a navigation bar which gets expanded automatically when the logged out. When logged in again, it will be expanded. It is automatically changing it class from `navbar-toggle collapsed`to `navbar-toggle`and `aria-exanded="false"` to `aria-expanded="true"`. NowI want to change the class `navbar-toggle` to `navbar-toggle collapsed` when logout is clicked in my jquery. I tried something like this :

In logout function, I added

```
$(this).toggleClass("navbar-toggle").toggleClass("navbar-toggle collapsed");
```

but I had no luck. How am I supposed to change the class here?
Please help me.

Comment: Hi Used to  this only $(this).toggleClass("navbar-toggle collapsed");

Comment: @ Rohit Azad I tried it. But it is not working for me.

Comment: Sathyanaranana Can you console to $(this)  i thing your  $(this) is not working can u please check to this and tell me

Comment: `$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');` try this... or `$('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');`

Comment: @ Guruprasad Rao It is working. Thank you so  much :)